# Why can't `cargo build` compile structopt-derive in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to write a small CLI application using Rust and the excellent structopt crate.

When I'm using Notepad++ (to write code) and Conemu (to run Cargo commands), everything works fine.

However, when I'm using VS Code with [Rust plugin](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls-vscode) (or Eclipse Corrosion), `cargo build` command fails with this error

```
   Compiling atty v0.2.10
   Compiling clap v2.31.2
   Compiling structopt-derive v0.2.10
error: linking with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe` failed: exit code: 1104
  |
  = note: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive0.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive1.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive10.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive11.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive12.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive13.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive14.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive15.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive2.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive3.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive4.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive5.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive6.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive7.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive8.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.structopt_derive9.rcgu.o" "/OUT:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.dll" "/DEF:C:\\Users\\NICOLA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc.NMAPUPGalI4H\\lib.def" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.crate.metadata.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.crate.allocator.rcgu.o" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsyn-e2bf8da738ad52ef.rlib" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\libquote-90431d93ebae45fd.rlib" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\libproc_macro2-f91721dd8e02bb17.rlib" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_xid-4611d062b1d773c0.rlib" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "proc_macro-1f431d761952eacf.dll.lib" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "syntax-c4a428491fc49b8f.dll.lib" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "rustc_errors-5b01c9a7974f0222.dll.lib" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "syntax_pos-09170bc016e0b11a.dll.lib" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "rustc_data_structures-f974a5ad0e93670e.dll.lib" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "serialize-2eb0aeb35010f869.dll.lib" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "rustc_cratesio_shim-2e9a42f968785601.dll.lib" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "std-81327c94ecbc69b1.dll.lib" "C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-e8d853735a158029.rlib" "opengl32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "setupapi.lib" "msimg32.lib" "credui.lib" "winspool.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "secur32.lib" "dbghelp.lib" "advapi32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "shell32.lib" "msvcrt.lib" "/DLL" "/IMPLIB:C:\\Users\\nicolas-delsaux\\Documents\\open-source\\rrss2imap\\target\\debug\\deps\\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.dll.lib"
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: impossible d'ouvrir le fichier 'C:\Users\nicolas-delsaux\Documents\open-source\rrss2imap\target\debug\deps\structopt_derive-406f571196e63046.dll'


error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `structopt-derive`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

It seems like some process has locked the output file, but LockHunter (which I use to detect that kind of locks) doesn't detect any...

What is the problem? What can I do - beside coding using Notepad++ - to be able to run cargo commands in VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's a bug in RLS : [Windows: RLS keeping derive plugin DLLs opened prevents `cargo build` from working #802](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls/issues/802)

> Whenever the RLS is running for a crate, I can't do cargo build for that crate. It fails with errors like this:
>
> [...]
>
> Looking in Process Explorer, RLS has the derive plugin DLLs loaded. I assume this is what's causing cargo to fail, since it can't write to those files while they're loaded. Similarly, cargo clean fails:
>
> [...]
>
> If I close VSCode (and thus RLS), building with cargo build works fine again.
>
> I assume this is Windows-specific due to its file exclusivity behavior. I think this started happening with a recent nightly (3/28?). I suppose this could've been caused by some change in cargo or rustc causing it to write to dlls which were already built or something.

So solution should be quite simple : update RLS to its latest version and see the bug being fixed !

And to update RLS, it's simply a matter of `rustup update`